# Wait until element is clickable Selenium Javascript Bindings

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

I am trying to click a button. For now I am simply trying to click it once and I know it will be there. This button gets loaded in with a bunch of other stuff by some JavaScript, and therefore takes a moment to be clickable. As of now, I am trying to click it in the following way:

```
const seeMoreBtn = await this.driver.findElement(showMoreBtnPath);
await waitUntilElementClickable(this.driver, seeMoreBtn, ONEMINUTE_TIMEOUT);
await seeMoreBtn.click();
```

I wrote the waitUntilElementClickable function, as I don't thinks it's a part of the JavaScript bindings. It is defined as follows:

```
async function waitUntilElementClickable(driver, element, timeout) {
    await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), timeout);
    await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(element), timeout);
}
```

When I run my code, I am getting the error

```
(node:16076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ElementClickInterceptedError: Element <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-binding"> is not clickable at point (743,865) because another element <div class="clearfix animate-show ng-isolate-scope ng-hide-add ng-animate ng-hide-animate ng-hide ng-hide-add-active"> obscures it
```

I can't attach a screenshot because of information on the page, but the driver is automatically scrolling to the element, and the ONEMINUTE_TIMEOUT is not being waited on, so I guess the element is Visible and Enabled.

Any tips on why this click is still being intercepted would be immensely helpful. Thanks! Also, I know that the waitUntilElementClickable function could theoretically double the timeout, it's just not a big deal at the moment.

Update: Quick fix suggested by @Prophet in comments is working for me. I replaced

```
await seeMoreBtn.click();
```

with

```
await this.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", seeMoreBtn);
```

Big thanks to @Prophet for helping me keep moving on my project.

Comment: Oh and this is with GeckoDriver, whatever the most recent stable version is.

Comment: In case you were using Java, C# or Python I'd, maybe, suggest you clicking that button with JavaScript, but since you are already using JS I don't know if there is an option to use something like `JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfb').click();");` here

Comment: @Prophet pretty sure I have an executor, let me try this and get back to you!

Comment: It flippin worked! Thanks @Prophet, this helps me a lot. I'd still like to understand what's happening, so I'll update the question and leave it here, but clicking via the executor works for what I need so thank you!

Comment: Great! I would like to answer this normally and give some explanations, but I don't know how to use executor with JS Selenium :)